# Xamarin.Forms Sqlite (sometimes) fetching bad result after update

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project which uses a local database file Sqlite (the file is called datas.lite) from sqlite-net-pcl nuget package (version 1.2.0).

I have a table called Item:

```
public class Item
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And a repository ItemRepository with a static connection SQLite, I use to update the Item rows:

```
public class ItemRepository
{
   private static SQLite.SQLiteConnection _conn;
   private static SQLite.SQLiteConnection Conn
   {
          get
          {
              if (_conn == null)
                  _conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection("myPath/datas.lite");
              return _conn
          }
   }
   public ItemRepository()
   {
       Conn.CreateTable<Item>();
   }
   public Item GetById(int id)
   {
       return Conn.Get<Item>(id);
   }
   // Retrieves all items from table Item
   public IEnumerable<Item> GetAll()
   {
        return Conn.Table<Item>();
   }
   
   // Updates the provided item
   public int InsertOrReplace(Item item)
   {
        return Conn.InsertOrReplace(item, typeof(Item));
   }
}
```

The app modifies the IsActive property for all items every 5 minutes by updating the Item table (The method TimerHelper.StartTimerInNewThread is called once at startup).

```
TimerHelper.StartTimerInNewThread(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delais), () 
            =>
            {
                try
                { 
                     // retrieve all items with DB
                     List<Item> items = repo.GetAll();
                     foreach (Item item in items)
                     {
                          item.IsActive = !item.IsActive;
                          if (repo.InsertOrReplace(item) == 1)
                          {
                               Log?.Info($"Item {item} has been updated in DB: IsActive = {repo.GetItem(item).IsActive}.");
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              throw new Exception($"InsertOrReplace() method returned a value != 1.");
                          }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log exception here
                }
            });
```

And immediately after updating the rows of table Item, I check (I log every IsActive property value for every Item) that the IsActive property of all items actually changed. So far, so good.
But if I let the application runs for several hours, sometimes, the check does not reflect the previous update...for instance, the application set the IsActive property for all items to TRUE, but the immediate request to the IsActive property returns FALSE for all items.

If I read via DbBrowser for Sqlite the table Item from the database local file (datas.lite), every item has its IsActive property set to TRUE, which is correct. So why the immediate read request I made after the update returned FALSE for all items, is there any caching that is active with sqlite? Or is it due to the fact that I have a static connection, and it is never closed, (it is moreover the recommanded way of doing according to microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows)

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please **add all relevant code** to your question. Otherwise, people are just guessing at what might be wrong. Without seeing any code, my first guess would be that there is somehow a "race condition" between the property update, and the check of their values.  I'm not sure what happens behind the scenes, but a general principle - not related to sqlite, but to making sure everything in app has been given a chance to complete its work - is to *queue* code to run a bit later, and perhaps on a specific thread. But doing that correctly depends on exact code details.

Comment: *"My application modifies the IsActive property for all items every 5 minutes by updating the Item table. And immediately after updating the rows of table Item, I check (I log every IsActive property value for every Item) that the IsActive property of all items actually changed. "* - that's the code to show. Including whatever sets that in motion. Is it running on a timer?

Comment: *"I log every IsActive property value for every Item"* - is there something that is growing larger and larger over the runtime? Is this a problem that "gets worse as time passes"? Or does it seem to be completely random as to when it fails?

Comment: If it was due to "caching", you'd see it immediately. It wouldn't be a random problem that happens infrequently. Either the app is "bogging down" over time, such that some timing issue that didn't immediately cause problems starts to increasingly reveal itself, or its a problem that is there all along, but with a low probability.

Comment: Thank you @ToolmakerSteve, I updated my post, to provide more information and code. It is actually running in a timer, and I think you are right it does not come from Sqlite caching, otherwise, I would see the problem right after the first update. But the problem is appearing randomly in fact. Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: But does it get worse as time passes? I know that’s hard to say for sure, but if you log a timestamp each time it happens, maybe can see if it becomes more common as hours pass. This distinguishes between purely random vs. something bogging down as time passes.

Comment: Once I notice that the requested IsActive value is wrong (false instead of true for example), the requested value stays wrong forever... The only way I can make the process works correctly again, is to delete the Data.lite file, and restart my application...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to protect timer code from being re-entered while it is still running.

Compare these three ways of running code repeatedly using a timer.

This is "typical" timer code. "seconds" is the time interval at which the work is done. Works fine if the code **always** finishes before the timer delay fires it again. Problematic if the timer code might take the ENTIRE time interval. (or if some background work, such as GC, takes enough time that your timer code eats the remaining time.) Really problematic if timer code takes so long that timer events start "piling up", starving the rest of your app from getting any time.

**TYPICAL "NAIVE" TIMER CODE**:

```
// Works fine if action is shorter than time delay.
// DON'T USE THIS CODE, if action might take longer than time delay.
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

    private void StartFixedDelayTimer(float seconds, Action action)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000 * seconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => action();
        // The timer event repeats until explicitly stopped.
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

---

**SKIP-IF-BUSY TIMER CODE**:

This is similar, but it protects itself by "skipping" work, if the work is still being done:

```
    // For long running "action", increase "idleSeconds" to guarantee more time for other background tasks.
    private void StartFixedDelayTimerSkipIfBusy(float seconds, Action action, float idleSeconds = 0.1f)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000 * seconds);

        bool entered = false;
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
            if (entered)
                // Timer code already running! Skip this one.
                return;
            entered = true;
            try {
                action();
                // IMPORTANT: This is needed to "see and skip" next timer event,
                // if it happens during "action". Without this, timer events can "pile up",
                // starving other background tasks.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)(1000 * idleSeconds));
            } finally {
                entered = false;
            }
        };

        // The timer event repeats until explicitly stopped.
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

---

**VARIABLE-DELAY TIMER CODE:**

This is an alternative approach. It doesn't request that the work be done again, until AFTER it finishes the first time. Here "seconds" is the amount of time between FINISHING the work, and the start of the next work. This is useful if you don't need the work done on a rigorous clock schedule. It has the advantage that no matter how long "action" takes, the rest of your app code gets "seconds" of cpu time before this work starts again - won't "starve" your app.

```
    private void StartDelayBetweenWorkTimer(float seconds, Action action)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000 * seconds);
        // Only fire the timer once. (But in Elapsed, we fire it again.)
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
            action();
            // Fire the timer again. Work will be done again "seconds" seconds after this statement is called.
            _timer.Start();
        };

        _timer.Start();
    }
```