# ImageRender exception on BindingContext when updating a high rate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting the following exception when drawing an image in iOS UI at a very high rate. I have ensure that I am updating the image source from the main thread. We have BLE devices broadcasting signal strength at a 750ms interval and I have ~ 50 around me. So as you could imagine, I am updating that image object often and quickly.  It works for a bit, then crashes with this exception.

Here is the exception on crash:

> at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00199] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:454
> at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0004d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:374
> at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyKey propertyKey, System.Object value) [0x0000e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:356
> at Xamarin.Forms.Image.SetIsLoading (System.Boolean isLoading) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Image.cs:81
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer.TrySetImage (Xamarin.Forms.Image previous) [0x000a4] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ImageRenderer.cs:104
> at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer.OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00055] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ImageRenderer.cs:85
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021
> at Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:178
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
> at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:73

Here is the code that updates the value, its nothing crazy... just an update to the set. I put a breakpoint in the `IsMainTread` just to make sure its not that, it never hits that.

Looking into the Xamarin Forms code based on the call stack, but best guess is that the `BindingContext` is becoming null somehow. Is there a way to make this safe or not update if it is?

Any reason I shouldn't be able to update an image at this rate?

```
private int signalStrength;
        public int SignalStrength
        {
            get
            {
                return signalStrength;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != signalStrength)
                {
                    if (!MainThread.IsMainThread)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("not here");
                    }
                    signalStrength = value;
                    if (Data.IsDownload)
                    {
                        SignalStrengthImage = "App.Resources.Images.TTSVGIcons.TTsignal_white_" +signalStrength+".png";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SignalStrengthImage = "App.Resources.Images.TTSVGIcons.TTsignal_" + signalStrength + ".png";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are setting SignalStrength from where? A timer? Event handler? The most likely problem is that the code "gets behind". The fix is to guarantee that executions (or event handler executions) are not "piling up" - if it gets behind, you have to throw away updates. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295920/199364) for two variations on "safe" timer code. If instead you have an event handler, you need to add code to "consume" all outstanding requests. This can be done by enqueing on event, then dequeuing ALL queued requests at once (only using most recent).

Comment: ... alternatively one can record time event arrives, then time event finishes processing. To detect if second event arrived before processing finished, in which case consider discarding it. The tricky part is writing code in such a way that event reception isn't blocked while you process previous event - so that you can observe events piling up. Done wrong, they'll still pile up, because you won't be told about each one until you've finished handling the previous one.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve your pile up comment is starting to make a lot of sense... we don't control the influx of data, its happening from the BLE devices and we are trying to process them on the BLE event notification as they come in.  So this is very very possible that we are falling behind as each one of these devices is broadcasting every 750ms and I have 50+ of them.

Comment: Ahh, 50 of them all at once. Maintain an array with most recent update timestamp for DISPLAY of each one. As each event comes in, queue it, including which one it is that updated. Have a processing loop to dequeue. In that loop, sleep for 5 or 10 milliseconds - to make sure events can be processed. (If events have higher priority, might not need that) Then dequeue ALL events that came in while sleeping (most of those will actually have come in while processing previous event). Check those display timestamps - OLDEST is the one to update display of next. TO keep all reasonably uptodate.