# Xamarin app shows blank page while looping

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making an Android application on Xamarin and I want this code to be looped over and over.
But when it's looping it shows literally nothing

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        string app = "notepad";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = httpClient.GetAsync("LINK/ob/ob.php?text=" + app).Result;
        var contents = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        string decider = contents.ToString();
        if (decider.Length > 7)
        {
            van.Text = "The " + app + " is ON";
            van.TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            van.Text = "The " + app + " is off";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please include the relevant code, properly formatted, in the body of your post.  Screenshots of code or errors are prohibited by the site rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, don't do this in the constructor.  Doing so guarantees that your page won't display until the code completes

second, instead of doing this in a loop with `Thread.Sleep()` use a timer instead

```
Timer timer;
int counter;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    timer = new Timer(2000);
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs a)
{
  counter++;
  if (counter > 100) timer.Stop();

  // put your http request code here

  // only the UI code updates should run on the main thread
  MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
  {
    if (decider.Length > 7)
    {
        van.Text = "The " + app + " is ON";
        van.TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        van.Text = "The " + app + " is off";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Basically correct, but `httpClient.GetAsync` could take longer than the time interval, "starving" the cpu, so display may get greatly delayed. [I use one of two "safe" techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295920/199364).

Comment: The code worked properly but it's not repeating itself because the label is not being updated every 2 seconds

Comment: you may need to wrap the actual UI update in a call to Essentials MainThread

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to do that. can you give me specific instructions?

Comment: see my last edit